# Physical trading spot transaction analysis-Quantified

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, trading, commodities, term-structure, spot-rate

ref to my previous question here:

[Physical commodity trading quantitative risk return model](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/39512/physical-commodity-trading-quantitative-risk-return-model) I am currently new to commodities and physical trading. I have currently narrowed down my area of analysis to spot transactions, and am looking for physical spot trade analytics. The closest I have come to any reading/examples is this masters thesis:

*Commodity market modeling and physical trading strategies (2010)*, by
Per Einar Ellefsen

https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/61602/704383331-MIT.pdf?...2

Does anybody know of any basic principles/writers/articles I can read on the quantitative aspects of physical spot trading?